# Generated button losing functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, local-storage

I am trying to build a webshop without using MySQL or any database, only with reading items from JSON and Storing them in LocalStorage. When page is just loaded, generated button is getting function, but after "Add to cart" button is clicked that is also generated but with AJAX , button loses functionality

```
    function load(){
    let listLoad = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    var keyLS = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)));
    listLoad += `<tr>
                 <span id="thisID" style="display:none">${keyLS.id}</span>
                 <td>${keyLS.name}</td>
                 <td>${keyLS.price}</td>
                 <td>${keyLS.quantity}</td>
                 <td><button type="submit"id="addOne" class="btn btn-success addOneItem">+</button></td>
                 <td><button class="btn btn-danger removeOneItem">-</button></td>
                 </tr>`


                }
     if(listLoad != ""){
         $("#cleanCart").css("display","inline");

     }
     document.getElementById('itsTboDy1').innerHTML = listLoad;
}
```

In the top I have AJAX that loads items from JSON file.

```
$(function(){
 $(".addOneItem").click(function(){

     console.log("lol");
 })
})
```

this works only once, when page is loaded

Comment: Where/how are you calling the function `load()`?

Answer (score 1):

This function

```
$(function(){
 $(".addOneItem").click(function(){

     console.log("lol");
 })
})
```

adds listeners to all `.addOneItem` elements present in the DOM *when the function is executed*. If the function `load()` creates new `.addOneItem` buttons to the DOM, it needs also to take care of adding the listeners to them.
Also, you didn't post the HTML, but I'm assuming the old button was inside the `#itsTboDy1` element, and the function `load()` overwrites it contents, destroying the old elements and event listeners with them.

Comment: No, there is no buttons in .addOneItem, its empty, could you give me one example of this "event" listener, if needed I can post all of the pages

Comment: `$(".addOneItem").click(function(){

     console.log("lol");
 })` attaches the event listener here. It means: find the elements of class .addOneItem, if a DOM event 'click' happens to them, execute the following function, namely write "lol" to the console.

Comment: I tryied, didnt work, the next asnwer man gave, did, thx anyway

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your button seems to be loaded dynamically. So the .click event wont work for the dynamic elements. I suggest try using .on method which will look something like

```html
$(function(){
 $(document).on("click",".addOneItem",function(){

     console.log("lol");
 });
});
```

Comment: This worked! Tyvm, searched for the answer for weeks!

Comment: Now when I am trying to add multiply rows to table, when I search for <span> text that I did hide in there, it adds values like to a string , if I have first item with ID=1 and one Item with ID=7 and trying to `console.log( $(this).parent().parent().parent().find("#thisID").text();)` it gives me 17 instead of only give me one ID from current <span>, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I didn't quite get you, but I guess the problem is that you are looping the same id for span in for loop and the id is duplicated. the id value should be unique for every element. try using the looping index i as a difference maker for every id.

Comment: I found a problem my parent() x100 did f1ck it up a bit, otherwise I did fix it